# Is it possible to override default destructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, overriding, destructor

I want to close WCF client connection whenever the class created that object is disposed or destructed by the destructor. These classes are those CodeFiles that holds code-behind of ASP.NET webforms. I already know that there is a garbage collector that does this. But what if I want to implement some operation just before garbage collector destroys the class instance? Is there any method I can override?

Answer (score 0):

> A destructor runs after a class becomes unreachable. It has the
>   special "~" character in its name. The exact time it is executed is
>   not specified. But it always runs when the class is not reachable in
>   memory by any references.

```
using System;

class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Constructor");
    }

    ~Example()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Destructor");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    Example x = new Example();
    }
}
```